# How to evaluate $\cos(22^\circ)\cos(38^\circ) - \sin(22^\circ)\sin(38^\circ)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How does one evaluate this? Does this generalize to $\cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)$?

Comment: Yes, check wikipedia under trig identities

Comment: You got the right idea. What you mentioned is cos(x+y).

Comment: yes if the angles are in degrees

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What's wrong with radian angles, if those were given instead?

Comment: nothing but $\cos(60)=1/2$ is then not true.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(22)\cos(38)-\sin(22)\sin(38)=\cos(22+38)=\cos(60)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A standard identity says $\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y=\cos(x+y)$, so you have $\cos(22^\circ+38^\circ)$.